# .htaccess Redirect/Rewrite Issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having a hard time figuring out how I can do this.

I want all requests to www.mydomain.com/manager to redirect to m.mydomain.com

I am trying:

```
# Friendly URLs for the manager
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?cloudcms.co$
RewriteRule ^manager/?$ http://m.cloudcms.co/ [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(m.|manager.)?cloudcms.co$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ manager/ [L,QSA,NC]
```

However, the only real one that is properly rewriting is the second condition.

I have also tried the following

```
# Friendly URLs for the manager
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?cloudcms.co$
Redirect 301 /manager http://manager.cloudcms.co

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(m.|manager.)?cloudcms.co$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ manager/ [L,QSA,NC]
```

But it ignores the second rewrite

Comment: Which URL isn't working for you?

Comment: the top one.  Trying to force all requests to www.mydomain.com/manager to redirect to m.mydomain.com

Comment: You have `P` flag there for proxying so it won't change the URL in browser but will still serve you content from `m.mydomain.com`

Comment: :)  thought of that as well.  still no dice

Comment: Ok then are you sure this `.htaccess` is in `DOCUMENT_ROOT`?

Comment: Is there another .htaccess in /manager` folder or any other in present `.htaccess`?

Comment: yes there was.  In fact that one was configured to turn off rewrites.  Now that I've gotten rid of it, it works

Comment: How would I be able to do this for any domain that could come in and try hitting the /manager folder?   Also, can you post this as an answer so I can accept :)

Comment: Oh that's great. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment above:

`Is there another .htaccess in /manager` folder or any other in present .htaccess`

I suspect OP has another `.htaccess` somewhere inside your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. Try removing that and this simple redirect will start working.

OP asked:

> `How would I be able to do this for any domain that could come in and
>   try hitting the /manager folder?`

Just change your first redirect rule to:

```
# if not already on mobile domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\. [NC
RewriteRule ^manager/?$ http://m.cloudcms.co/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to `P` flag, which is reverse proxying for you. Try replacing that with an `R`:

```
RewriteRule ^manager/?$ http://m.mydomain.com/ [NC,L,R]
```